# RabbitMQ upgrade from 3.6.6 to 3.6.11

Tags: rabbitmq, upgrade

I have a question related to RabbitMQ upgrade from 3.6.6 to 3.6.11.

Is it possible to upgrade directly from 3.6.6 to 11 or we should go step by step.

In the release notes, it is stated that 3.6.11 doesn't have incompatibility issues with 3.6.7 walking through 3.6.10, what about 3.6.6?

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/tag/rabbitmq_v3_6_11

Does anyone have prior experience with upgrading RabbitMQ?

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade a non-clustered RabbitMQ from one major or minor release to another simply install the new version and restart it. All configuration and persistent message data is retained.

In case of clustered RabbitMQ setup there are some caveats. Please refer to the following link for upgrading RabbitMQ cluster:
http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html#upgrading

As a side note, please refer the release notes before upgrading for any key announcements.

FYI: We did a non-clustered RabbitMQ upgrade on our production setup by simply installing the latest version and restarting it. Everything worked fine.